# How do I write a write a view in django that gets an object_list based on a field?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a simple tag model and a simple project model.

In the project model I have a m2m to the tag model.

I want to return all the projects with a tag. I'm almost there.

Right now the view below returns **invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cheap'**

So, it has the right slug, and it's making the query, but it's trying to get the list of projects based on the id of the m2m tag.

Any suggestion much appreciated.

My Tag Model:
class Tag(models.Model):

```
"""
A basic tag model for projects
"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)
    verbose_name = _('Tag')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Tags')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

@models.permalink
def get_url_path(self):
    return ('TagDetail', (), {'slug': self.slug})
```

My url:

```
# tags/<slug>/ The detail view for an archived project
url(regex=r'^tags/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    view=TagDetail.as_view(),
    name='tag_detail',
),
```

My view I'm trying to figure out:

```
class TagDetail(ListView):
""" Get all projects for a tag """

template_name = "projects/TagDetail.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    tags = get_list_or_404(Project, tags=self.kwargs['slug'], displayed=True)

paginate_by = 10

@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(TagDetail, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: To clarify, this is using class based generic views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Project model looks like this

```
class Project( models.Model ):
  tags=models.ManyToManyField( Tag )
```

match to the tag's slug

```
def get_queryset( self ):
  return get_list_or_404(Project, tags__slug=self.kwargs['slug'], displayed=True)
```

the only change being `tags__slug`.

Comment: yes, that makes sense and it now doesn't produce the error. However, that was almost it.

Comment: oops. forgot the solution. I need to return tags to the get_queryset otherwise there is nothing in the list. Thanks for the help!